# Solution for floating icons over different divs in different position

Tags: jquery

For example I have two div containers like the one below:

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^<br/>
DIV 1 container|<br />
%%%%%%%%|


^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^<br/>
DIV 2 container|<br />
%%%%%%%%|
```

The first one (Div1) is one top of Div 2.
I would like to float an icon on one of these div corners (top-left, top-right,bottom-left,bottom right).

For the first div, it would be pretty easy since I could use jQuery to get the width and height of the div and compute the corner coordinates. So for example if the first div dimension is:

1240 =width
375= height

I get these dimensions using jQuery:

```
    var heightdiv1=$('div1').height();
    var widthdiv1 = $('div1').width();
```

The following are the coordinates computed in JS:

Compute Bottom right coordinates:

left=1240-1240*0.1=1116=
top=375-375*0.1=337.5

Compute Bottom left coordinates

left=0
top=375-375*0.1=337.5

Compute Top right coordinates:

left=1240-1240*0.1=1116
top=0

Compute Top left coordinates:

left=0
top=0

Then I could append the icons to the div using jQuery and using the position:absolute to get that floating effect:

```
$('#div1').append('<a href="#"><img src="/test/icon.jpg" style="position:absolute; top: '+top+'px; left: '+left+'px"></a>');
```

This recipe works perfectly but only for the first div. For the second div (DIV2) or any other div in the page, it won't land on the correct corners.

I believe i can still get the correct div dimension for any other divs but I find it hard how to position my icon on their specific corners like what I did on the first div.

I've tried using .offset() but I don't know if it can compute the corner positions. If anyone can give some tips, it would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What the heck are you trying to draw with all those `^^^%%%`'s?

Comment: question: do you know CSS top vs bottom, right vs left ?

Comment: Wow, that looks complicated and unnecessary. This can be done with CSS alone. `div { position: relative } div a { position: absolute; }` and icon should be positioned top-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the div elements `position:relative` and give the anchor (not the img) element that you're appending `position:absolute`.

When you use absolute positioning it is still relative to the nearest "positioned" (i.e., not `static`) ancestor, so for your purpose you don't need to calculate any offsets.

(And, not necessary to make it work but much neater, rather than using an inline style on the elements you're appending just give them a common class.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mSLRN/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, if I add position:relative, can it affect the target div layout? I'm concerned it might get distorted or something. I want the target div layout style untouched. If adding position:relative does not hurt, this is a great solution. What do you think? Sorry if I ask questions like this, I'm not a CSS expert. Thanks.

Comment: If you set `position:relative` but leave the defaults for `top`, etc., then it won't adversely affect the div.